# Issue with function scope - function is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working in an app built with NodeJS. I am using modules, here is my code so far:

**CODE: PROGRAM.JS**

```
var path     = process.argv[2];
var ext      = '.' + process.argv[3];
var prsFiles = require('./fpmod');

function callback(err, files) {
    if(!err) {
        success(ext, files);
    } else {
        throw ('uhoh there was an error! :/');
    }
}

prsFiles.process(path, ext, callback);
```

**CODE: FPMOD.JS**

```
var fs      = require('fs');
var pathMod = require('path');
var i       = 0;

function success(ext, files) {
    for(i; i < files.length; i++) {
        // console.log('File comes in as: ' + files[i] + ' and we\'re filtering on .' + ext);
        var currentFile    = files[i];
        var currentFileExt = pathMod.extname(currentFile);
        // console.log('grabbed ext is: ' + currentFileExt);

        if(ext) {
            if(ext === currentFileExt) {
                console.log(currentFile);
            }
        } else {
            console.log(currentFile);
        }
    }
}

function processFiles(path, ext, callback) {
    var success = success;
    fs.readdir(path, callback);
}

exports.process = processFiles;
```

The error I am getting says that the **success function is not defined**. Why is that? If my understanding of function scopes is correct, it should have access to the success function! What am I getting wrong?

Comment: FYI, `var success = success;` in `processFiles` shadows the outer `success` function and leaves the local `success` variable `undefined`. However, that's not your  main issue. As already mentioned in the answers, JavaScript has *lexical* scope! not dynamic scope. I.e. a function has only access to the bindings that exist at the moment the function was *defined*, not when it is *called*. One solution could be to pass `success` as argument to the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scoping in JavaScript is lexical. What matters is the set of symbols visible to code in a function at the time the function is defined. I guess it's more accurate to say that it's the set of *scopes* at the point of definition that matters. Function scopes are (excepting `delete`, which is weird and disallowed in strict mode anyway) immutable in terms of the set of symbols they export, but the global scope isn't. Module scope works like function scope (I think; I admit to not being a Node expert.) However the global scope isn't really in question here because you're working with modules.

Your "callback" function, defined in your main module, has access to no symbol called "success" at the point that it's defined. The fact that the function in the other module has a local symbol called "success" cannot help - that symbol is completely alien to the "callback" function. That's just not something you can do in JavaScript.

Remember that in the Node environment, unexported symbols in a module are effectively private to that module.

Answer (score 1):

You are not exporting the `success` function.

You are expecting it to be present in the first snippet, even if you didn't do anything to make it available. You could do something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  processFiles: processFiles,
  success: success
};
```

and then use it

```
var prsFiles = require('./fpmod');

function callback(err, files) {
  if(!err) {
    prsFiles.success(ext, files);
  } else {
    throw ('uhoh there was an error! :/');
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't. The exercise forbids me to do this. I must only expose one function in my module.

Comment: Please provide more details then, one other solution might be to pass in success instead of `callback`, but that depends on your requirements.

Comment: Apologies. I am following the 'Make It Modular' tutorial in [LearnYouNode](https://github.com/rvagg/learnyounode).